# Jquery selector with variables and find

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to write a Jquery selector that uses a variable to add an active class to a list item.

The variable `sv` is either `'dom-site'` or `'int-site'` which corresponds to the id of a list item. The html looks like this:

```html
<ul class="">
  <li id="int-site" data-display="International" data-site="https://cms.csu.edu.au/study/international/home" class="cohort-select" tabindex="0">international student information</li>
  <li id="dom-site" data-display="Domestic" data-site="https://cms.csu.edu.au/study-futurestudents/home" class="cohort-select" tabindex="0">domestic (Aust/NZ) student information</li>
</ul>
```

My Jquery is this:

```
$('div[id$="cohort-switch"] ul').find('li[id*="+sv+"]').addClass('active');
```

Comment: do you want to add class to the last list item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should separate your variables from the strings

```
$("div[id='cohort-switch'] ul").find("li[id='" + sv + "']").addClass('active');
```

OR use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for easy concatenation.

```
 $("div[id='cohort-switch'] ul").find(`li[id='${sv}']`).addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#'+svg).addClass('active');
```

That simple

Comment: @ObitoUchiha tnks for advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can clearly see, that `('li[id*="+sv+"]')` is badly formatted.

You should use `('li[id*='+sv+']')` or just `$('#'+sv).addClass('active');`

Answer (score 0):

You could either use `sv` to append as string:

```js
'li[id*="' + sv + '"]'
```

```js
let sv = "dom-site";
$('div[id$="cohort-switch"] ul').find('li[id*="' + sv + '"]').addClass('active');
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cohort-switch">
  <ul class="">
    <li id="int-site" data-display="International" data-site="https://cms.csu.edu.au/study/international/home" class="cohort-select" tabindex="0">international student information</li>
    <li id="dom-site" data-display="Domestic" data-site="https://cms.csu.edu.au/study-futurestudents/home" class="cohort-select" tabindex="0">domestic (Aust/NZ) student information</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or use [`template string`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
`li[id*="${sv}"]`
```

```js
let sv = "dom-site";
$('div[id$="cohort-switch"] ul').find(`li[id*="${sv}"]`).addClass('active');
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cohort-switch">
  <ul class="">
    <li id="int-site" data-display="International" data-site="https://cms.csu.edu.au/study/international/home" class="cohort-select" tabindex="0">international student information</li>
    <li id="dom-site" data-display="Domestic" data-site="https://cms.csu.edu.au/study-futurestudents/home" class="cohort-select" tabindex="0">domestic (Aust/NZ) student information</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like below**

```js
var sv = 'dom-site';
$('ul').find('#'+sv).addClass('active');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="">
  <li id="int-site" data-display="International" data-site="https://cms.csu.edu.au/study/international/home" class="cohort-select" tabindex="0">international student information</li>
  <li id="dom-site" data-display="Domestic" data-site="https://cms.csu.edu.au/study-futurestudents/home" class="cohort-select" tabindex="0">domestic (Aust/NZ) student information</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you haven't used the same `id` elsewhere, you can simply try   `$('#'+sv).addClass('active')` . If you want to add class to the last list item the use `$('li:last').addClass('active')`

```js
var sv ='dom-site'
$('#'+sv).addClass('active');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="">
  <li id="int-site" data-display="International" data-site="https://cms.csu.edu.au/study/international/home" class="cohort-select" tabindex="0">international student information</li>
  <li id="dom-site" data-display="Domestic" data-site="https://cms.csu.edu.au/study-futurestudents/home" class="cohort-select" tabindex="0">domestic (Aust/NZ) student information</li>
</ul>
```